# Would the gate in Path of Pain stay open if i saved and quit?

Tags: hollow-knight

I'm playing hollow knight on my switch, and one day i thought it would be a good idea to try and to path of pain for fun. I got about what i think is halfway (the chorus is singing in the background) and i hit a lever that made a gate open. However, i want to play other games on my switch now, but because theres no save points in Path of Pain, i was thinking i could just save and quit, and the gate would still be open when i came back. But i dont want to risk losing all of my progress on Path of Pain because... well... it's Path of Pain. It's hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rest at a bench to save, and since there are no benches in the Path of Pain, you'll have to exit the area and rest at a bench. But yes, if you rest at a bench and quit, the shortcut opened by the lever will be open when you come back.

Comment: You actually don't need to rest at a bench to save. If you quit at any point, your progress will be saved and you will be moved to the last bench you rested at.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the gate does stay open. If you rage-quit (which I did), then as long as you can make it  back to the area with the shortcut, you can use it freely, although if you save quit you respawn back at the bench just below the PoP.